# Dynamics 365 FO Data Entities: staging table is empty

Tags: axapta, dynamics-365-operations

I am trying to test data entities on our D365FO ISV solution. So I created a data entity with custom entity SalesTable as data source. But exporting only creates an Excel file with a header but zero rows. Please see below.
[image]

SalesTable has data:
[image]

I ran the export in the front end (tried both Azure SQL DB and Excel) and it executed succesfully (showing 0 rows under Exported):
[image]

The SalesContractsStaging table also stays empty:
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to export in same legal entity where the data exists?

Comment: What happens if you use the standard sales order entity for export? Btw, TREX is an awesome company id ;)

Comment: We're going to test it today FH-Inway. And Pradeep thanks for you answer, the company is not the issue.